# I can't use Tor's socks5 proxy on safari

Tags: socks, safari

I had tried privoxy to build a listen-address on 0.0.0.0:8118. But whatever I use socks proxy of 127.0.0.1:9150 or http/https proxy on 127.0.0.1/0.0.0.0:8118,Tor will not work on my safari. However,I can use Tor on my iphone using http proxy of 8118. What can I do to make my safari on Tor to work. Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Why not just use the Tor browser? That would be far more secure than using Safari.

Comment: as far as i concerned,safari is much more beautiful than tor browser.

Answer (score 2):

You need to do some steps to get Privoxy working with Tor and Safari.

1. Open the Privoxy config file and search for *9050*. You'll find the line: `#        forward-socks5   /               127.0.0.1:9050 .`. Remove the `#` at the beginning of the line. If you're using Tor Browser, Tor listens on port 9150, so change the 9050 to 9150. If you have installed a system-wide Tor, it listens on port 9050 and you're all set.
2. Restart Privoxy.
3. Make sure your Tor software runs (either as system-wide daemon or by starting Tor browser).
4. Open Safari and change the proxy settings 127.0.0.1:8118
5. Go to https://check.torproject.org/ and see if everything is working.

Comment: I'm sure my tor and privoxy are working well.'cause my virtual machine use my tor-privoxy well and https://check.torproject.org shows everything is working.I set up my tor-privoxy on my mac.And I just can't use them on my mac.I had tried to set up them on my fedora virtual machine on my mac and set host's system proxy to my tor.But it didn't work.Only my firefox with proxy set on my mac can use tor.I think I should use another server or computer to set up tor and privoxy or I can't use tor on my safari.Sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are not able to connect to the Tor network is because you are not sending requests to the correct port.  If I am not mistaken, Tor operates on port 9050, so your browser should be listening to 127.0.0.1:9050, not 127.0.0.1:9150.  For more information on this topic, please look [here](https://www.torproject.org/docs/faq#TBBSocksPort).

Comment: thx for your answer.but i check my torrc-defaults file,it writes socks port is 9150.and my parallels can use privoxy's proxy and on tor's route.i have check my 9050,it's empty.

Comment: That is really odd.  Can you post the file on pastbin/bay for viewing?

Comment: what file?torrc or pictures that record how i use tor's socks proxy?is pastbin/bay pastebin/bay?sorry i am really not good at english.

Comment: do you main [this](http://pastebin.com/2r7YE1r9#)?

Comment: Stand-alone Tor by default sets SocksPort 9050, but in the Tor browser it's 9150.